# How to pass Collection of parameters to chaining pattern API in Scala

Tags: scala

I am using JAVA library where its API is built on chaining pattern, like:

```
(new SomeClass).method1("data1").method1("data2").method2("data6")
```

My data is in list:

```
val list = List("data1","data2","data3","data4")
```

I want to pass them as parameters for each method1 call. My current version is:

```
list.foldLeft(new SomeClass)((a,b)=>a.method1(b))
```

Is there more appropriate or idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Convert it as a java collection and use it in the very same way as you would in java?

Comment: List can be in different sizes. And only way to pass parameters is to call method1 with all parameters one by one.

Comment: If `method1` returns the same SomeClass it was invoked on, you could do `list.foreach(a.method1(_))